# What is the difference between Herbrand Logic and Relational Logic or Predicate Logic?

Tags: logic, relations, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I am learning a course from Stanford University, and it introduces the notion of Herbrand Logic. However in Wikipedia I cannot find a definition specifically for "Herbrand Logic", only for Herbrand Base or Herbrand Theorem, concepts that also exist in relational locic / predicate logic ?

Answer (score 3):

See [here](http://logic.stanford.edu/intrologic/notes/chapter_06.html) for *Relational Logic*.

Is first-order predicate logic without function symbols, i.e. tehre are only $n$-ary relation constants.

The semantics is based on *Herbrand semantics*.

Due to the lack of function symbols, the interpretation has only a finite number of objcets; thus, we can use *truth assignments*, as in propositional logic, and use them to evaluate formulas.

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question. This is just an explanation of first-order logic.

Answer (score 3):

"Herbrand Logic = First-order syntax + Herbrand semantics".

Essentially, in Herbrand semantics a model M is a set of ground terms, which are exactly those ground terms that it satisfies. In other words, a model is always some subset of the Herbrand base.

This is very different from the Tarski semantics, where a model may contain a whole bunch of elements that cannot be written down as ground terms, but they can take part in the interpretation. In particular, the quantifiers range over such elements as well.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a first order language L.

In first order logic: A formula F follows from a set of formulas T if every first order structure for L that satisfies T also satisfies F.

In Herbrand logic: A formula F follows from a set of formulas T if every first order Herbrand structure for L that satisfies T also satisfies F.